# Performance Issue for the Angular Mat-Table

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have a mat-table which load data from JSON file. If I load 100 rows then the site becomes slow and it takes 1 min to load the table.

From the browser performance, I got to know, `ZoneDelegate.invokeTask` is triggered and continue checking recursively. everywhere it is `callViewAction`.

What would be the solution to this issue?

[image]